# ThreeJS: Get useful shader build log

Tags: three.js, shader

When my ThreeJS custom shaders contains errors, I get the very cryptic `INVALID_OPERATION` message in the JS console during the rendering stage:

```
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid
```

Is there a way to get a more useful log, such as the one returned by [getShaderInfoLog()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getShaderInfoLog)?

*(To test this quickly, one can add errors in the shaders of [this app](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/three-cube-experiment).)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For performance reasons, `three.js R104` does no longer perform error checking and reporting when shader programs are being compiled. However, multiple users complained about this change so it was recently reverted. With the next release `R105`, things will be as before (see [migration guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r104--r105)).

However, you can manually turn on the previous behavior in `R104` by setting `renderer.debug.checkShaderErrors` to `true`.

Comment: Awesome, it's working! It's documented [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.checkShaderErrors). To be honest, I prefer v104: having something optimized, and explicitly have to setup a debug flag when required ;-)